# Can't send and Image using NFC

Tags: java, android, nfc

I have a method that, when I click on a button, sends via NFC an image to another smartphone. The code seems correct and the execution arrive at the last line of code but nothing happens. Both smartphones have NFC and Android Beam. Here is the code:

```
public void sendFile(View view){
    nfcAdapter=NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    if(!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enable NFC",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS));
    } else if (!nfcAdapter.isNdefPushEnabled()) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enable android beam",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFCSHARING_SETTINGS));
    } else {
        //If we got here, Nfc and Android beam are enabled
        Toast.makeText(this,"Ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String fileName="test.jpg";
        File fileDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File fileToTransfer =new File(fileDirectory,fileName);

        Toast.makeText(this,"Tutto Ok2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fileToTransfer.setReadable(true,false);
        Uri fileUri=Uri.fromFile(fileToTransfer);
        if(fileUri==null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"File not found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{
            //If we got here, the app has found the image and is ready to send it
            Toast.makeText(this,"Tutto Ok3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Send the image
            nfcAdapter.setBeamPushUris(new Uri[]{Uri.fromFile(fileToTransfer)},this);
        }

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Beam communication can't be started on a click.

See official doc: [Sharing Files with NFC](https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/index.html):

> This feature has a simple API and allows users to start the transfer
>   process by simply touching devices.

One device must touch the other one to activate Beam communication.
You could allow beam transfer on a click but after devices must be touch.

Please read :

- [Sending Files to Another Device](https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/send-files.html)
- [Receiving Files from Another Device](https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/receive-files.html)

For instance to send file to another device:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    // Flag to indicate that Android Beam is available
    boolean mAndroidBeamAvailable  = false;

    // Instance that returns available files from this app
    private FileUriCallback mFileUriCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // NFC isn't available on the device
        if (!PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)){
            /*
             * Disable NFC features here.
             * For example, disable menu items or buttons that activate
             * NFC-related features
             */
            ...
            // Android Beam file transfer isn't supported
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <
                Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            // If Android Beam isn't available, don't continue.
            mAndroidBeamAvailable = false;
            /*
             * Disable Android Beam file transfer features here.
             */
            ...
            // Android Beam file transfer is available, continue
        } else {
            mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
            /*
             * Instantiate a new FileUriCallback to handle requests for
             * URIs
             */
            mFileUriCallback = new FileUriCallback();
            // Set the dynamic callback for URI requests.
            mNfcAdapter.setBeamPushUrisCallback(mFileUriCallback,this);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Callback that Android Beam file transfer calls to get
     * files to share
     */
    private class FileUriCallback implements
            NfcAdapter.CreateBeamUrisCallback {
        public FileUriCallback() {
        }
        /**
         * Create content URIs as needed to share with another device
         */
        @Override
        public Uri[] createBeamUris(NfcEvent event) {
            // List of URIs to provide to Android Beam
            Uri[] mFileUris = new Uri[1];

            String transferFile = "transferimage.jpg";
            File extDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
            File requestFile = new File(extDir, transferFile);
            requestFile.setReadable(true, false);
            // Get a URI for the File and add it to the list of URIs
            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(requestFile);
            if (fileUri != null) {
                mFileUris[0] = fileUri;
            } else {
                Log.e("My Activity", "No File URI available for file.");
            }
            return mFileUris;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even using this code, NFC doesn't work..the image exists but It doesn't send it (Naturally I changed the path of the resource)

Comment: Edit: As my first code, it works 1 time out of 10.. and I don't understand why

Comment: What step doesn't work ? when touch or during transfer or ... Do you hav log in logcat ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using another smartphone. The code works correctly. Some devices have problems with NFC (tested on LG G2 and Nexus 5)